# Head and tail in one line

Tags: python, list, tail, head

Is there a pythonic way to unpack a list in the first element and the "tail" in a single command?

For example:

```
>> head, tail = **some_magic applied to** [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
>> head
1
>>> tail
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Comment: Remember that lists are not implemented as singly-linked lists in Python, so this operation is costly (as in: the whole list needs to be copied). Depending on what you want to achieve, this might or might not be a problem. I am just mentioning that because this type of list destructuring is often found in functional languages, where it is actually a very cheap operation.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Under Python 3.x, you can do this nicely:

```
>>> head, *tail = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
>>> head
1
>>> tail
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

A new feature in 3.x is to use the `*` operator in unpacking, to mean any extra values. It is described in [PEP 3132 - Extended Iterable Unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). This also has the advantage of working on any iterable, not just sequences.

It's also *really* readable.

As described in the PEP, if you want to do the equivalent under 2.x (without potentially making a temporary list), you have to do this:

```
it = iter(iterable)
head, tail = next(it), list(it)
```

As noted in the comments, this also provides an opportunity to get a default value for `head` rather than throwing an exception. If you want this behaviour, [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) takes an optional second argument with a default value, so `next(it, None)` would give you `None` if there was no head element.

Naturally, if you are working on a list, the easiest way without the 3.x syntax is:

```
head, tail = seq[0], seq[1:]
```

Comment: sorry, I used the term tail unproperly. I mean what I say in the example, that is the list without the first element

Comment: @Giacomod'Antonio My mistake, I didn't read closely enough. What you said is the normal meaning of tail. Actually, that makes it even simpler.

Comment: Can you update a little about complexity of `head, tail = seq[0], seq[1:]` vs `head, *tail = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]`. 2nd option still has O(N) complexity, instead of O(1)?

Comment: @NikolayFominyh They are both the same - they both take the head element and construct a new list containing the tail elements. No difference in complexity. Another class could implement `__getitem__`/`__setitem__` to do the tail operation lazily, but the built-in list does not.

Comment: On a list of 800 elements doing it 1M times, I have 2.8s for the head, *tail = seq solution and only 1.8s for head, tail = seq[0], seq[1:] solution. Slicing is still faster for lists.

Comment: What's the performance of this? Are python lists capable of doing O(1) head, tail?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai No, Python's main list class is an array list. This would be O(n) as it involves copying the tail to a new list (with one O(1) get for the head).

Comment: This nice syntax is another reason to move to `python 3.x`

Comment: If `seq` is empty, a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0)` exception is thrown. Is there a way to have `head` assigned `None` in this case (other than catching the exception, of course)?

Comment: @Simone Only if you fall back to the method I gave for 2.x - `next()` takes a second argument which is a default value, so `next(it, None)` would do what you want. Catching the exception as you describe would probably be the simplest choice. Obviously you could also check for length first if you were working with a list or something, but this does introduce a potential race condition and requires a known length (which isn't true of an arbitrary iterable).

Comment: Love this answer, thanks. You can also unpack more items before reaching for the *rest:
`nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]`
`head, neck, *tail = nums`
`# head == 1`
`# neck == 2`
`# tail = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Answer (score 40):

```
>>> mylist = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
>>> head, tail = mylist[0], mylist[1:]
>>> head
1
>>> tail
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Answer (score 13):

For O(1) complexity of `head,tail` operation you should use `deque` however.

Following way:

```
from collections import deque
l = deque([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
head, tail = l.popleft(), l
```

It's useful when you must iterate through all elements of the list. For example in naive merging 2 partitions in merge sort.

Comment: It seems like deque(list_instance) has O(N) complexity. Am i wrong?

Comment: @НикитаКонин, you are right about construction of deque. However, if you want to access first element more than once, then `head, tail = l.popleft(), l` is ~O(1). `head, tail = seq[0], seq[1:]` is O(n).

Comment: It looks like you can just do `head = l.popleft()` and `tail` is just an alias for `l`. If `l` changes `tail` changes too.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2, using lambda

```
>>> head, tail = (lambda lst: (lst[0], lst[1:]))([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55])
>>> head
1
>>> tail
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Comment: why in the world would you do this instead of just `head, tail = lst[0], lst[1:]`? if OP means to use a literal then he could split head and tail manually `head, tail = 1, [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]`

Comment: (1) Op's question was whether it's possible to do this in one line (so no `lst = ...` in previous line). (2) Doing `head, tail = lst[0], lst[1:]` leaves the code open to side-effects (consider `head, tail = get_list()[0], get_list()[1:]`), and is different than Op's form `head, tail = **some_magic applied to** [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]`.

Comment: That being said, I acknowledge that this is a bad obfuscated way to get the head/tail. But I thought it was the best answer for Python 2 for Op's specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the [Python 2 solution from @GarethLatty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532492/4099593), the following is a way to get a single line equivalent without intermediate variables in Python 2.

```
t=iter([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]);h,t = [(h,list(t)) for h in t][0]
```

If you need it to be exception-proof (i.e. supporting empty list), then add:

```
t=iter([]);h,t = ([(h,list(t)) for h in t]+[(None,[])])[0]
```

If you want to do it without the semicolon, use:

```
h,t = ([(h,list(t)) for t in [iter([1,2,3,4])] for h in t]+[(None,[])])[0]
```