# parse a list into variable and sublist - pythonic way

Tags: python, list, parsing

I am parsing a list into a variable and another list with this script:

```
b=[' 687.3774', ' 478.6', ' 47', ' 58', ' 96.90']
c,d=b[0],b[1:]
```

It is always the first element that would be separated and this code works fine, however, it repeats the list `b` on the right hand side. This is not a *problem* but it does get annoying when my `b` is something big like `line.replace('*',',').replace(' ',',').split(',')`. This doesn't really look like the pythonic way of writing this down. I have read some posts in this forum and the documentation on tuples and etc but nothing quite did the trick for me. Below are some things that I tried in a "shot in the dark" manner and that obviously didn't work

```
d=[]
c,d[:]=b
c,list(d)=b
c,d=b[0],[1:]
```

I am also aware of the `b.pop` method but I could not find a method to use that without repeating `b` in the RHS.

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10532492/2003420) shows one way of doing it in Python 3 - the same way suggest in one of the answers. But not way in Python 2 seems to do want you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, you can try

```
c, *d = b
```

It will assign `b[0]` to `c` and the rest to `d`. You should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python) question's answers for an explanation on how the `*` operator works on sequences.

Comment: Note that it's only compatible with python 3. Otherwise I guess adding a new line that covers the whole `line.replace ... split()` routine isn't a poor choice.

Comment: @Igor i was unaware of its compatibility, thanks. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: No problem :) There's also a detailed explanation on extended unpacking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking. It's a really neat feature in py3k, I wish I used it more :(

Comment: Thanks for the reading suggestions. Unpacking in py3k _is_ neat. Too bad I can't import that syntax into py2. I guess I'll just add one more line to the code, like @IgorHatarist suggested.