# How to sum a column grouped by other columns in a list?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a list as follows.

```
[['Andrew', '1', '9'], ['Peter', '1', '10'], ['Andrew', '1', '8'], ['Peter', '1', '11'], ['Sam', '4', '9'], ['Andrew', '2', '2']]
```

I would like sum up the last column grouped by the other columns.The result is like this

```
[['Andrew', '1', '17'], ['Peter', '1', '21'], ['Sam', '4', '9'], ['Andrew', '2', '2']]
```

which is still a list.

In real practice, I would always like to sum up the last column grouped by many other columns. Is there a way I can do this in Python? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

dynamically grouping by all columns except the last one:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [25]: df.groupby(df.columns[:-1].tolist(), as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum()).values.tolist()
Out[25]: [['Andrew', '1', 17], ['Andrew', '2', 2], ['Peter', '1', 21], ['Sam', '4', 9]]
```

Comment: Does [0,1] represents the first column and the second column?

Comment: @Deepleeqe, yes, i've also added another version where it's done dynamically for any number of columns...

Answer (score 10):

This is an O(n) solution via [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), adaptable to any number of keys.

If your desired output is a list, then this may be preferable to a solution via Pandas, which requires conversion to and from a non-standard type.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [['Andrew', '1', '9'], ['Peter', '1', '10'], ['Andrew', '1', '8'],
       ['Peter', '1', '11'], ['Sam', '4', '9'], ['Andrew', '2', '2']]

d = defaultdict(int)

for *keys, val in lst:
    d[tuple(keys)] += int(val)

res = [[*k, v] for k, v in sorted(d.items())]
```

**Result**

```
[['Andrew', '1', 17], ['Andrew', '2', 2], ['Peter', '1', 21], ['Sam', '4', 9]]
```

**Explanation**

- Cycle through your list of lists, define keys / value and add to your `defaultdict` of lists.
- Use a list comprehension to convert dictionary to desired output.

Answer (score 9):

Op1

You can pass a index `sum`  and add tolist convert back to list

```
pd.DataFrame(L).\
   set_index([0,1])[2].astype(int).sum(level=[0,1]).\
        reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[78]: [['Andrew', '1', 17], ['Peter', '1', 21], ['Sam', '4', 9], ['Andrew', '2', 2]]
```

---

Op2

For list of list you can using `groupby` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import groupby
[k+[sum(int(v) for _,_, v in g)] for k, g in groupby(sorted(l), key = lambda x: [x[0],x[1]])]
Out[98]: [['Andrew', '1', 17], ['Andrew', '2', 2], ['Peter', '1', 21], ['Sam', '4', 9]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Create to `DataFrame` and aggregate third column converted to integers by first and second columns, last convert back to `list`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
L = df[2].astype(int).groupby([df[0], df[1]]).sum().reset_index().values.tolist()
print (L)
[['Andrew', '1', 17], ['Andrew', '2', 2], ['Peter', '1', 21], ['Sam', '4', 9]]
```

And solution with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), python 3.x only:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532492
for *head, tail in L:
    d[tuple(head)] += int(tail)

d = [[*i, j] for i, j in sorted(d.items())]
print (d)
[['Andrew', '1', 17], ['Andrew', '2', 2], ['Peter', '1', 21], ['Sam', '4', 9]]
```

Answer (score 6):

#### `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize([tuple(x[:-1]) for x in data])
v = np.array([x[-1] for x in data], int)

[list(k) + [int(v)] for k, v in zip(u, np.bincount(f, v))]

[['Andrew', '1', 17], ['Peter', '1', 21], ['Sam', '4', 9], ['Andrew', '2', 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Added my 2 cents. Both of these use `groupby`, `agg`

V1: introduces the new sum function.

```
sum=lambda x: x.astype(int).sum()
print(df.groupby([0,1], as_index=False).agg({2: sum}).values.tolist())
```

---

V2: converts the column to numeric

```
df[2] = pd.to_numeric(df[2])
print(df.groupby([0,1], as_index=False).agg({2: sum}).values.tolist())
```

And will return:

```
[['Andrew', '1', 17], ['Andrew', '2', 2], ['Peter', '1', 21], ['Sam', '4', 9]]
```