# get string slices in a groupby statement python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to group by the ID field and get last letters in GG field. For example, say I have the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'ID':['Q'] * 3,
         'GG':['L3S_0097A','L3S_0097B','L3S_0097C']

})

print (df1)
  ID         GG
0  Q  L3S_0097A
1  Q  L3S_0097B
2  Q  L3S_0097C
```

I am trying to groupby ID column and get only last letter in GG column and add it to the defaultdict like this:

```
{'Q': ['A','B','C']}
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
mm = df1.groupby('ID')['GG'].str[-1].apply(list).to_dict()
and also tried the following code:
for i, j in zip(df1.ID,df1.GG):
    mm[i].append(j[-1])
```

but both din't work. May I know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use syntactic sugar - [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by - 2 `Series` - `GG` Series with last value and `df1['ID']`:

```
mm = df1['GG'].str[-1].groupby(df1['ID']).apply(list).to_dict()
```

Or [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) only last value back to `GG`:

```
mm = df1.assign(GG = df1['GG'].str[-1]).groupby('ID')['GG'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

---

```
print (mm)
{'Q': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
```

Pure python solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mm = defaultdict(list)
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532492
for i, j in zip(df1.ID,df1.GG):
    mm[i].append(j[-1])

print (mm)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Q': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
```

Comment: thanks.. it worked.. but may I know how can I do it with zip statement? because when I tried using the above posted zip code, I get the error like this:     "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'  "

Comment: @amrutha - I think need `defaultdict` for this.