# How to add key value from a dictionary into a new dictionary after looping over in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have tried looping through this list and the dictionary at its index. I intend to get the key-value pairs into a new dictionary.

```
travel_log = [
{
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 12,
  "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]
},
{
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 5,
  "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]
},
]

new_dict = {}
for key in travel_log[0]:
    new_dict = key
print(new_dict)
```

The code above just loops into it and adds the last key looped over to the new dictionary, meanwhile, I want all the key values "countries", "visits"
and "cities" to be there.

Comment: a similar question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73675464/sum-of-only-couple-of-indexes-of-lists-in-a-dictionary/73837559#73837559

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of only couple of indexes of lists in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73675464/sum-of-only-couple-of-indexes-of-lists-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

`travel_log` is a list of dictionaries **list(dict())**
if want to copy the first element of the travel_log to a new dictionary then do this:

```py
new_dict = travel_log[0]
```

upd:
as Serge Ballesta noticed below, the dictionary is a mutable data type; In oder to create a new object you can use dict()

```py
new_dict = dict(travel_log[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new_dict = {}
for key,value in travel_log[0].items():
    new_dict[key] = value
print(new_dict)
```

Output

```
{'country': 'France',
 'visits': 12,
 'cities': ['Paris', 'Lille', 'Dijon']}
```